# Regex to remove <select> elements

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string representing a select option group in HTML, I want to use regex in Python to remove the `<select>` elements leaving only the `<option>` and `<optgroup>` in my final string.

```
<select id="id_permissions" multiple="" name="permissions">
      <optgroup label="Auth">
          <option value="4">Can view permission</option>
          <option value="8">Can view group</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
```

**How do I do this?**

This regex isn't working either, I am hoping someone can help guide me with this :

`^(?=.*?\<select\b).*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we would use a simple expression:

```
<select.+>\s*(<[\s\S]*>)\s*<\/select>
```

which our desired output is being captured in this group:

```
(<[\s\S]*>)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ryJxxz/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"<select.+>\s*(<[\s\S]*>)\s*<\/select>"

test_str = ("<select id=\"id_permissions\" multiple=\"\" name=\"permissions\">\n"
    "      <optgroup label=\"Auth\">\n"
    "          <option value=\"4\">Can view permission</option>\n"
    "          <option value=\"8\">Can view group</option>\n"
    "      </optgroup>\n"
    "</select>")

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use BeautifulSoup 4?

#### Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """
<select id="id_permissions" multiple="" name="permissions">
      <optgroup label="Auth">
          <option value="4">Can view permission</option>
          <option value="8">Can view group</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
str(soup.find('optgroup'))
'<optgroup label="Auth">\n<option value="4">Can view permission</option>\n<option value="8">Can view group</option>\n</optgroup>'
```

Comment: +1 because I actually use beautiful soup and this is valid... However in my instance I am literally passing html (soup-ajax) through a Django template and that selection didn't work as I needed due to extra data being appended (somehow)... Regex works perfectly